# How to obtain Rakanishu's Blade after patch 2.0?

Tags: diablo-iii

Before patch 2.0, Rakanishu's Blade was a guaranteed drop from Avatar of Rakanishu (or event reward?) *on Normal*. Now, tiered difficulties being removed, how does one get Rakanishu's Blade?

Will farming with low-level characters do?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think the reason why Rakanishu's Blade didn't drop in nightmare/hell was because the base item's ilvl is too low for it to drop. You should be able to get this running a lower level character to do the quest, but I don't know how low you need to be.

Comment: While answers are true and reassuring, here's a hint: try asking around in achevement-focused communities. Someone is likely to lend you the Blade for the achievement, or just give away. Just be sure to give it away, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rakanishu's Blade is a lvl 16 magic sword.

I tried to get it with a lvl 16 character, but the items i got were lvl 12 or 13, and I didn't find the event again before I was too high level and got lvl 20+ items.
I can't tell you the exact needed level, but my guess would be between 17 and 20.

What you could do is have a low level character create the game and invite a friend with higher level who could find the event quickly and do the killing while you stay in town to avoid getting exp.
When he finds the event, let him kill everything and wait for you to destroy the shrine. If the items are too low level, level up once and try again.

Comment: Thanks for testing! I'll test more extensively when I have the time.

Comment: I just had a clan member drop the blade with a level 70 character, in Torment I.
Seems there is no required level, but the blade isn't a guaranteed drop anymore.
Also, his blade is now account bound (but I don't know if it dropped that way, or if he used the mystic on it, but I doubt that because I don't think Myriam can work on blue items), and got a orange, legendary-like affix "When you kill a Fallen, you a have xx% chance to charm all other nearby Fallen."

Comment: My bad, he had a Marquise gem in it, and I totally forgot gems were now account bound too, so that's probably just because of that.

Comment: still thanks for the info. Curious about that legendary effect now! :-)

Comment: @Helbrecht: Rak's blade is a legacy item, so it's account-bound by default. Also, Myriam can't enchant legacy items. +1 for the info on getting the blade to drop regardless of level, though.

Comment: @WillR. False. Legacy items are not account bound - people are trading legacy Witching Hours left and right (as one of the few legacy items still viable at level 70). Also, I have personally gotten *Bashanishu* by finding Bashiok and inviting a guy who lent me the Blade.

Comment: Ah, I think I know why: the blade that I have in my stash is from way back in 1.0.5, so I bet it's being considered a legacy item for a different reason. Either way, thanks for catching me on that one. Please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: I tried starting with level 15, three times at each level, and didn't get the blade until level 21 (first time on that level). It had the new legendary ability (although it was still just a blue item).

Answer (score 5):

it would seem creating a low-level character is not necessary. Refer to an [entry on diablo.wikia.com](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Rakanishu%27s_Blade) - there is a screenshot of a 2.0 Rakanishu's Blade and the title claims that:

> Found after killing Rakanishu on a bounty with a level 67 character.

So it would seem there is a hope to find it after all ;-)